# Put javascript in external file with MVC Razor (dynamic)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

An example is the easiest way to explain this one. I am working with code that has lots of javascript inside `<script>` tags on the actual page. I normally like to put javascript in external files (plus then it's better for refactoring when you find things in common across many pages). The difficulty is that the code if full of dynamic function names, class names and ids... like this:

```
 function handlePosData@(mySuffix)(data) {
        $('#myDiv@(mySuffix)').css('cursor', 'auto');
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
            $('#lstPos@(mySuffix)').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(data);
        }
    }
```

`mySuffix` is a GUID generated at the top of the the Razor code

(I am brand-new to this codebase, so don't ask me WHY it is like this. The web app can have many different popups open at once, and I am assuming this is a solution to the need to ensure unique names ... )

Any ideas how to enable keeping the same scheme, but with external javascript files?

Answer (score 1):

I take it these functions are called from your razor page (rather than an external js file).  If so you can do the following:

Change the function so it is standard and instead of using the razor directly in the function, use a js variable:

```js
// this can be moved to external js
function handlePosData(data, mySuffix) { // pass in mySuffix to function so it is a js var
  $('#myDiv' + mySuffix).css('cursor', 'auto');
  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    $('#lstPos' + mySuffix).data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(data);
  }
}
```

Then in your razor code, you just call the function like this:

```
handlePosData(data, '@(mySuffix)'); // not sure what your data is so just left that as a var that you pass in
```

Comment: Yes, but  also the *function name itself* has the "mySuffix" as part of it. That's the tricky issue.

Comment: @kpollock: You should be able to do something like `window['handlePosData' + mySuffix]` to define the function, and call it in the same way (`window['handlePosData' + mySuffix](data)`). However, that's going to be a huge pain. It would be far better to use a generic name for the function, and if there's different versions of it based on the suffix, you can employ different namespaces.

Comment: @Pete: This answer is technically correct, but the OP should be encouraged to properly namespace these kind of variables, rather than polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Oh, I would never have done it this way - it is existing code, and I am new in the job and don't want to start a huge debate/fight ...yet! There may be perfectly "good" reasons (ie some weird tool or 3rd party library) but I just do not know. Antagonising my colleagues is not high on my priority list right now.

Comment: @ChrisPratt how is this polluting the global namespace? OP was asking how to move the function into an external js file, to do that, you need to remove the razor from the js - all I have done is made the function a single name rather than one for each suffix, and then I have passed a local variable into the function - where is the global pollution?

Comment: @kpollock that's what I'm saying, your function name doesn't need the suffix on it

Comment: I am almost scared to ask why it does.... or why the GUID (because that is what mySuffix is) is generated each page load - I mean ..Globally Unique, the clue is in the name. I will end up posting on thedailywtf if I am not careful!